# cropping a specific image from sdcard

Tags: crop

i want to crop an image present in sdcard .My code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        Uri  uriOfImageToCrop = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/bookpage.jpg");
        intent.setDataAndType(uriOfImageToCrop, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriOfImageCrop);
        startActivity(intent);
```

But it showing the following exception:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't include a crop API anymore. You need to create your own or import one like :
https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage